# What is the complexity of an arithmetic progression?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I dont really understand how to calculate the complexity of a code. I was told that i need to look on the number of actions that are done on each item in my code. So when I have a loop that runs over an array and based on the idea of arithmetic progression (I want to calculate the sum from every index till the end of the array) which means at first i pass over n cells and the second time n-1 cells and so on... why is the complexity considerd O(N^2) and not O(n) ?

As I see it, n + n-1 +n-2 + n-c.. is xn -c , In other words O(n). SO WHY am i wrong ?

Comment: Why ? Because `x = n/2`, it is not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is telling to do is the following :-

```
traverse array from 1 to n
traverse array from 2 to n
... similarly after total n-1 iterations
traverse array's nth element
```

As you can notice that array traversing of cells is decreasing in order of 1.

Each traversal is being guided by loop which is increasing upto value of i. The whole code is wrapped under a function of n.

The concrete idea for ***number of actions performed on each item of the array*** is :-

```
for ( i = 1 to n )
for ( j = i to n )
traverse array[j] ;
```

Hence, complexity of your code = O(n^2) and the order is clearly in AP as it forms the series n + (n-1) + ... + 1 with a common difference of 1.

I hope it is clear...

Comment: I see the logic behind what you say. But how can you explain the fact that on an array {1,2,3} I pass on totaly 6 cells and not 9 ?

Comment: On an array of {1,2,3},you first start traversing array of {1,2,3}---traverse elements 1,2 and then 3. Next, your array become sub-array, and now,you need to traverse only {2,3}. Next,again, your array becomes further shorter. Now, you only need to traverse {3}. Hence, `the array was traversed in all possible ways to generate sum`.

Comment: can you help me in another question please ? - if i want to count the sequence in the arrays that has the max sum, how can I do it when I have a limit of O(n) time complexity ?

For example : {1,2,3,4,-3} the output will be 4 because the sum of 1+2+3+4 is the maximum sum and there are 4 numbers in that sequence

I know how to do it with O(N^2) time complexity but not with O(n)

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question as it'd be too broad to answer this in the comment over here.

Comment: i need to wait 90 minutues to do so :(

Answer (score 4):

> As I see it, n + n-1 +n-2 + n-c.. is xn -c , In other words O(n). SO WHY am i wrong ?

Actually, it is not true. The sum of this arithmetic progression is n*(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)

P.S I have read your task : you need only one loop over an array using the previous results, so you can solve this one with O(n) complexity.

```
for i=1 to n 
 result[i] = a[i]+result[i-1]
```

Comment: but I dont look on the total sum of the arithmetic progression, i want to look on the time complexity of the whole code which is one loop

Comment: @MarielCherkassky If you are doing n iterations,than n-1 and so on .. - you should count the total sum of iterations and it will quadratic. But, you can solve this task by using only one iteration over the array - and then it will be O(n)

Comment: @shekharsuman If I correctly understand the task - it can be solved by "memorising" previous results with O(n) complexity : 
 for i=1 to n
  index_sum[i]=a[i]+index_sum[i-1]

Comment: but the total sum of inerations isnt quadratic. look on an array with 3 cells, the total sum of inerations is 6

Comment: @MarielCherkassky you need to represent a number of iterations by some function of n. The total sum is quadratic : because your algorithm does n*(n-1)/2 iterations - it's a quadratic function .

Comment: @ig-melnyk- You'd have been right considering memorisation,but, now, *Check my answer. You people will know why your answer is incorrect.* Your earlier edit was correct as I hinted.

Comment: @MarielCherkassky-Check my answer. It'll help you understand the complexity and why it's O(n^2).

Comment: @shekharsuman I am just saying that author's algorithm is O(n^2) but it can be modified to be O(n) . There is no doubt that his current algo is quadratic

Comment: @ig-melnyk-Then you're damn correct. Sorry for pointing in wrong-direction. I'd have upvoted your answer,but, I have already finished my quota of 40 upvotes in a day...

Comment: @shekharsuman it's ok. Didn't know that there are limitations for upvoting

Comment: @ig-melnyk- Finally able to upvote your answer. Cheers and sorry again for incorrectly pointing at your answer. I couldn't get the meaning of your answer in first hand.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is: `1 + 2 + ... + n`.

This is equal to `n(n+1)/2`.

For example, for n = 3: `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`
and `3(4)/2 = 12/2 = 6`

`n(n+1)/2 = (n^2 + n) / 2` which is `O(n^2)` because we can remove constant factors and lower order terms.

Answer (score 0):

As an arithmetic progression has a closed form solution, its efficient computation is o(1): that is its computation time does not depend on the number of elements.

If you were to use a loop then it would be o(n) as the execution time would be linear on the number of elements.

Comment: So in this exercise (I want to calculate the sum from every index till the end of the array the time complexity would be O(n) or O(n^2) ?

Comment: This answer is incorrect as the original answer will be O(n^2). I don't have downvoting power for today else I'd have utilised over here. The other answer is correct!

Comment: Is it really an ap? Could you paste up the first few terms?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding up n numbers whose average value is (n/2) because they range from 1 to n. Thus n times (n/2) = n^2 / 2. We don't care about the constant multiple, so O(n^2).

Comment: Lets say i have an array {1,2,3) i calculate 3 sums : 1+2+3 , 2+3 and 3, when i run over the array i pass on 6 cells totaly,  how can it be O(n^2) in that case ?

Comment: I thought you were doing n + (n-1) + (n-2), which in this case is 3 + 2 + 1, no?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong somewhere! The sum of an arithmetic progression is of the order of n^{2}

To clear your doubts on arithmetic progression, visit this link: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html

And as you said, you face difficulty in finding the complexity of any code, you can read from these two links:

http://discrete.gr/complexity/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html

Good enough to get you going and help you understand how to find the complexity of most of the algorithms.